# "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexoutofrangeexception

i am trying to make battleship( in germany its called sink ships) And i have a problem, which is described in the title. There is nothing more to say, but i have to write something so i can post this.
Can somebody pls help me, i do not see the problem

```
from random import randint

class Spiel():

    def __init__(self):
        self.feld = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
        for i in range(0,10):
            for e in range(0, 10):
                self.feld[i].append(0)
    def place(self):
        boats = [5,4,4,3,3,3,2,2,2,2]
        for e in boats:
            while True:
                ausrichtung = randint(0,1)
                if ausrichtung==0: ##Horizontal
                    z1 = randint(0, 9-e)
                    z2=randint(0,9)
                    abschnitt = self.feld[z2][z1:(z1+e)]
                    if  not(1 in abschnitt) and  not(2 in abschnitt) :
                        schiff=[]
                        for i in range(0,e-2):
                            schiff.append(1)
                        self.feld[z2][z1:(z1+e)]=[2,*schiff,2]
                        break
                elif ausrichtung==1: ##Vertikal
                    z1 = randint(0, 9)
                    z2=randint(0,(9-e))
                    z3 = z2
                    lp=0
                    for m in range(0, e):
                        if self.feld[z2][z1] ==1 or self.feld[z2][z1]==2:
                            lp +=1
                        z2 += 1
                    if lp <1:

                        schiff=[]
                        for i in range(0,e-2):
                            schiff.append(1)
                        self.feld[z3:(z3+e)][z1]=[2,*schiff,2] # PROBLEM HERE
                        break
        print(self.feld[0:1])
        print(self.feld[1:2])
        print(self.feld[2:3])
        print(self.feld[3:4])
        print(self.feld[4:5])
        print(self.feld[5:6])
        print(self.feld[6:7])
        print(self.feld[7:8])
        print(self.feld[8:9])
        print(self.feld[9:10])


spiel = Spiel()
spiel.place()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 56, in <module>
    spiel.place()
  File "test.py", line 40, in place
    self.feld[z3 : (z3 + e)][z1] = [2, *schiff, 2]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: What are the values of the offending variables?  How did they get to take on those values?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following print statement before the line in which your code breaks reveals the following:

```
print(len(self.feld), z3, (z3 + e), len(self.feld[z3 : (z3 + e)]), z1)
self.feld[z3 : (z3 + e)][z1] = [2, *schiff, 2]
```

```
10 1 6 5 1
10 2 5 3 8
Traceback (most recent call last): ...
```

It seems that `z1` is `8`, yet `self.feld[z3 : (z3 + e)]` has a length of `3`. Your issue is in the way the `[z1]` is indexing. Perhaps the following line:

```
z1 = randint(0, 9)
```

Is the culprit. :)

Comment: And what can i change?

Comment: Let's think together for a bit. If `self.feld[z3 : (z3 + e)]` has a length of `3` at some portion of the loop, should you be initilizing `z3` as a random integer between `[1, 9]`? ... and if not, what should you do?

Comment: z3 isn't between [1,9], its between [0,(9-e)]

Comment: Oh, I see the new code update. Then perhaps `[0, (9-e)]` is not the correct indexing for the list `self.feld[z3 : (z3 + e)]` and therefore you should concentrate on trying to figure out why `[0, (9-e)]` is not properly indexing it your list. Your code is a bit too convoluted for someone who doesn't know what is going on to try to debug it. Instead of `(9 - e)`, you could make it more dynamic: `z3 = randint(0, len(self.feld[z3 : (z3 + e)]))`

Comment: i will look for the problem later because i have no time right now, but thanks anyways :-)

Comment: Ofc. Sorry I couldn't provide a direct answer, but as I said, I'm not too sure what your goal is to begin with, so hard to debug unless I was to spend a solid 15-20 minutes understanding the code to begin with. The error has been found, and more importantly the _why_ of the error. Now that you know the _why_, debugging shouldn't be hard. :)